# How to add a new row to DataGridView using a button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

In a C# Windows application, I'm using a DataGridView to display all the data. I want to add a new row to the grid when the user clicks the Add New Row button. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manipulate Rows in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddtce152.aspx

onclick of button add row by using dataGridView.Rows.Add as shown below in example

```
 // Populate the rows.
        string[] row1 = new string[]{"Meatloaf", 
                                            "Main Dish", boringMeatloaf, boringMeatloafRanking};
        string[] row2 = new string[]{"Key Lime Pie", 
                                            "Dessert", "lime juice, evaporated milk", "****"};
        string[] row3 = new string[]{"Orange-Salsa Pork Chops", 
                                            "Main Dish", "pork chops, salsa, orange juice", "****"};
        string[] row4 = new string[]{"Black Bean and Rice Salad", 
                                            "Salad", "black beans, brown rice", "****"};
        string[] row5 = new string[]{"Chocolate Cheesecake", 
                                            "Dessert", "cream cheese", "***"};
        string[] row6 = new string[]{"Black Bean Dip", "Appetizer",
                                            "black beans, sour cream", "***"};
        object[] rows = new object[] { row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6 };

        foreach (string[] rowArray in rows)
        {
            dataGridView.Rows.Add(rowArray); // addding row 
        }
```

Comment: @Pranay Rana:: If I want to add unlimited rows then what I do?

Answer (score 0):

In your onclick event, are you calling DataTable.Rows.Add() or similar?